# Numbering sections doesn't work

Tags: numbering

I'm new to Latex and I'm making a big document with a lot of sections, subsections etc. Could anyone find out why the sections numbering doesn't appear in the PDF?
Here is my preamble:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref} % options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\parindent\z@}{\parindent\z@\leavevmode}{}{}
%\patchcmd{\ttlh@hang}{\noindent}{}{}{}
%\makeatother
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdfborder={0 0 0},
  breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
%\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
    \usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\input{part1ch1}
```

`part1ch1.tex` looks like:

```
\section{text...}
```

Comment: Off topic: Is it necessary to make a document with such a complicated preamble?

Comment: You have issued `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}`. Nothing will be numbered.

Answer (score 1):

Each sectional unit within a standard document has a *level*, and this level is indicated by a *number*:

- `\part` = -1
- `\chapter` = 0
- `\section` = 1
- `\subsection` = 2
- `\subsubsection` = 3
- `\paragraph` = 4
- `\subparagraph` = 5

Using

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{<num>}
```

will number all sectional units that have a *level* less than or equal to `<num>`. In your preamble you declared

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
```

which effectively means that no divisions will be numbered. If you want subsections to be numbered, use

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```